# Java - ScrollPaneLayout - Customising the vertical scrollbar background, slider and arrows

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I'm attempting to build a custom JScrollPane to be more specific as indicated in the design image below.

I'm having problems with the following tasks:

**Customising the vertical scrollbar background, slider and arrows**:
I'm having problems in customizing the scrollbar - to be more specific:

- Changing the vertical scrollbar background to yellow
- Changing the scrollbar slider color to another color
- Creating the JScrollPane border to contain radius edges on the border
- Changing the scrollbar arrows color to another color

[image: test]

For the border I was successful with my attempts to change it to yellow. Here's the code:

```
class MyScrollPane extends JScrollPane {

    public MyScrollPane(Component view) {
        super(view, VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);        
        this.setLayout(new MyLayout());        
        setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

.

```
class MyLayout extends ScrollPaneLayout {

    public MyLayout() {
        super();
    }

    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        super.layoutContainer(parent);        
        vsb.setSize(vsb.getWidth() , vsb.getHeight()); // drift
        vsb.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW));        
    }  
}
```

Regarding the background I was unsuccessful - for example the following doesn't work:

```
vsb.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Any ideas/thoughts would be very helpful as I've been stuck for several days.

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JScrollPane

Comment: please why shouting, then any feel from this thread has the opposite effect, no issue to answering your question, nothing special, but please for why ....